# Comment Editing Time

Tags: discussion, comments

Why are you only allowed to edit your comment for five minutes after it is posted? It seems to me it would be handier to be able to edit it anytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always delete a comment, and always add another - the idea of editing comments is more about fixing up silly typos, rather than crafting them into an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking more along the lines of realizing you put an incorrect link 10 minutes later, or something like that, but I guess it makes sense to just add a new comment to fix it.